# how to load multi .rec file in MXNet?

Tags: python, mxnet

When I have a .rec file, whenever I need to add new data, I have to pack a new .rec, which is time consuming and wasteful. Is there any way to design an dataiterator to read multiple .rec? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have 2 sub-questions:

1. **Is it possible to append data to a recordIO file?** [The question was
   asked on the MXNet forum](https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/append-records-to-recordio-dataset/3142) couple months ago, where some answers
   (and drawbacks of this solution) are written
2. **Is it possible to train from multiple .rec file?** Yes, this question was also [asked and answered on the MXNet forum](https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/load-multiple-rec-files-for-shuffling-and-training/3794)